# IS it possible to load controller.js on every request in angularjs to load updated controller

Tags: angularjs

We have an application in **angularjs** and **html**. `pages.Index.html` is the main page which load all controllers and directives.Is there any way to load `controller.js` on demand when I call its corresponding view instead of loading whole application.

Comment: I guess you can use ngRoute to load controllers depending on the view that is requested. But not sure if ngRoute would satisfy your application, since more info on your application is needed. Please explain more about your application so that I can detail on ngRoute.

Comment: @ZohaibAkram, Yes, you can specify controller that you need to execute on the `state configuration`.

Comment: @ Abhilash P A- Pullelil . we are using ui-route.My problem is when i do changes in my controller.I donot get changes when i reload its view .Because  controller.js is loaded before when my index page calls.Controllerjs will reflect changes when i reload index page which loads all referances.

Comment: @ZohaibAkram , By changes in controller, do you mean to say that, you edit the controller code in controller.js **by hand** and those changes are not getting reflected when the view reloads??

Comment: @ Abhilash P A- Pullelil. Yes exactly i want changes in controller when view reload by an ajax call.

Comment: @ZohaibAkram Changing and Loading the controller.js does not seem to be a 'normal' process that is followed. Possible to explain exactly why you are doing so? It might help us to better understand your problem and provide a better solution.